# Android, is there a onInflated Function?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

Hi i have a XML page and a class which is dynamically inflated

```
public class CmsPage extends LinearLayout

<my.package.CmsPage xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Now i want that my CmsPage automatically inflates subViews... but in the constructor it is too early. Is there an onCreate function for LinearLayouts ?

I tried with an OnPreDrawListener, but this is to late since i want to fill my member variables in this function, like the onCreate of my activity.

Comment: Why is constructor too early?

Comment: because in the constructor subviews defined in the xml are not available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinearLayout extends [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), which has a method called `onFinishInflate()`

Comment: Thanks that's it! I'll accept this answer as soon as possible